# Source drive of my installation

Tags: boot, drive

I have cloned by HDD to a SSD using clonezilla. That means I have two drives which are exactly the same. How do I know which Ubuntu got booted up from inside Ubuntu, the HDD or SSD one.

Output of `lsblk` is attached. `sda` is HDD and `nvme0n1` is SSD
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output you show, you can tell that the root drive of your running system is `/dev/sda2`. That partition is mounted on `/`, the root directory.

The device name suggests that this is the regular hard drive, `/dev/sda`. The SSD drive is `/dev/nvme0n1`.

So this is how you can know which Ubuntu got booted up from inside Ubuntu, by looking at the mount mounts.

Remark that your efi partition in contrast is mounted on your SSD, i.e. on `/dev/nvmeOn1p1`. Where `/` and `/boot/efi` are mounted is configured in `/etc/fstab` of the booted partition.